# Get all values from queryset using templates

Tags: python, django

I am trying to retrieve all the queryset data (names and amount) using templates.

views.py

```
def get_expense(request):
    #expenses = list(Expense.objects.values())
    expenses = Expense.objects.values('name' , 'amount')
    
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ExpenseForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            post = form.save(commit=False)
            post.save()

            #print(driver_text)
            print(type(expenses))
            return render(request, 'thanks.html', {'expenses':expenses}) #JsonResponse(expenses, safe=False) #

    else:
        form = ExpenseForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html',{'form':form})
```

thanks.html:

```
{{ expenses }}
```

I am trying to get all those queryset data listed but instead I am getting:

```
<QuerySet [{'name': 'Home Rent', 'amount': 8000.0}, {'name': 'hjvhjvhv', 'amount': 73.0}, {'name': 'tes', 'amount': 23.0}, {'name': 'dddd', 'amount': 34.0}, {'name': 'qqqqqqqq', 'amount': 56.0}, {'name': 'dddddddddd', 'amount': 34.0}, {'name': 'dddddddddxxxxxxxx', 'amount': 34.0}, {'name': 'dddddddddd', 'amount': 34.0}, {'name': 'dddddddddd', 'amount': 34.0}, {'name': 'dddddddddxxxxxxxx', 'amount': 56.0}, {'name': 'dddddddddxxxxxxxx', 'amount': 56.0}, {'name': 'dddddddddxxxxxxxx', 'amount': 56.0}, {'name': 'dddddddddxxxxxxxx', 'amount': 56.0}, {'name': 'dddddddddxxxxxxxx', 'amount': 56.0}, {'name': 'new', 'amount': 45.0}, {'name': 'new', 'amount': 45.0}, {'name': 'new', 'amount': 45.0}, {'name': 'new', 'amount': 45.0}, {'name': 'new', 'amount': 45.0}, {'name': 'hjvhjvhv', 'amount': 67.0}, '...(remaining elements truncated)...']>
```

I need only the name and amount listed instead of the whole queryset.

Comment: Show us an example of what you want ! Something like [{'Home rent': 8000.0}, {...}, ...] ?

Comment: I want something like this:
`name: 'Home Rent'
amount: 8000.00

name: hjvhjvhv
amount: 73.00

name: tes
amount: 23.00

.... Till the last element..`

All should be in separate lines.

Comment: You already have it in your example, when you pass it to the template it behaves as a dict. What is your problem? Doesn't it work?

Comment: Have you tried `expenses = Expense.objects.all()` and in it `index.html` you can use `for loop` like {{ expenses.name }}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In your .html file, loop through expenses like this :**

```
{% for expense in expenses %}
<div>
name: {{ expense.name }}, amount: {{ expense.amount }}
</div>    
{% endfor %}
```